# How to make scrollIntoView method work in Laravel dusk

Tags: laravel-dusk

Description:
The scrollIntoview dusk method is not working as expected.

Can anyone please point me the right version of laravel/dusk, chrome driver version to be used to make it work again.

Currently I am using theses versions while running the script.
Laravel framework version: 6.2
laravel/dusk: 6.11
php:7.2
Chrome driver: 88.0.4324.96.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is a wide range of unexpected behaviours in `scrollIntoView()`, and related reasons...

Among the many: [my own experience](https://blog.madbob.org/scroll-and-fall/) was about the Bootstrap navbar placed above the scrolled element, resulting in many "Other element would receive the click" errors. I fixed it with my own Browser Macro, scrolling the element at the bottom of the page (instead of top):

```
\Laravel\Dusk\Browser::macro('scrollView', function ($selector) {
  $selector = addslashes($this->resolver->format($selector));
  $this->driver->executeScript("document.querySelector(\"$selector\").scrollIntoView({block: 'end'});");
  $this->pause(500);
  return $this;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to permanently fix this long-standing, annoying problem by adding the `--disable-smooth-scrolling` option in `DuskTestCase.php`:

```
$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
    "--window-size=1920,1080",
    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
    "--disable-smooth-scrolling" // add this
])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function ($items) {
    return $items->merge([
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--headless",
    ]);
})->all());
```